# Can i use Doctrine with Zend_XmlRPC

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, xml-rpc

I am with the follow problem, when i try to return an response from doctrine to my client using Zend_Xmlrpc, i got this message Failed to parse response, the answer in question is an bidimentional array.
I tryed to make my own array, by hand, and return it... and this worked fine.
There´s one way to return an Doctrine Object to an Zend_Xmlrpc?
Or I´ll have to make all the data access by hand?

Thanks !

I found something, the problem was not on doctrine, but on the size of the response... by passing an limit that i make, I got an  correctly answer, however I can´t get the full response, there´s an way to increase that max size?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine 1 objects have some circular references so when you use automatic conversion (PHP Object to XMLRpc) the data after conversion might be simply infinite (Zend might be stopping conversion after some time).

You need to implement your own toArray() and fromArray(array $array) on your Doctrine model so you can easily serialize it to pure PHP array and then pass it to XML RPC.